# Render partial template from different cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

We are installing telegraf agents on multiple application server nodes; as part of the monitoring framework to collect server metrices

This is done by out master cookbook.

*master/recipe/telegraf_install.rb*

```
yum_package 'telegraf' do
  source "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{node['telegraf']['package']}"
  action :install
end

template '/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf' do
  source node['telegraf']['template_name']
  owner 'telegraf'
  group 'telegraf'
  mode '0777'
  variables(
    partial_name: node['telegraf']['partial_name'],
    app: node['telegraf']['app'],
    env_name: node['telegraf']['env_name'],
```

This master cookbook has the default configuration template as well.

*master/template/telegraf_install_default.conf.erb*

```
# Telegraf Configuration.
[global_tags]
  ## Environment variables can be used as tags and throughout the config file (i.e. user = "$USER").
  app = "<%= @app %>"
  env_name = "<%= @env_name %>"
  env_type = "<%= @env_type %>"
  role = "<%= @role %>"

<% unless @partial_name.empty? -%>
 <%= render @partial_name %>
<% end -%>
```

There are other template files under templates/ as well

*master/template/Partial1.conf.erb*

```
# Partial1 service
[[inputs.procstat]]
pattern = "Pattern1"

[inputs.procstat.tags]
service_name = "Service1"
instance = "Instance1"
```

*master/template/Partial2.conf.erb*

```
[[inputs.proc]]
pattern = "Pattern2"

[inputs.proc.tags]
service_name = "Service2"
instance = "Instance2"
```

All this time, we used to write role files under master cookbook itself

*master/role/Application1_DEV.json*

```
"default_attributes": {
            "telegraf": {
                "template_name": "telegraf_install_default.conf.erb",
                "app": "App1",
                "env_name": "DEV1",
                "env_type": "DEV",
```

*master/role/Application1_UAT.json*

```
"default_attributes": {
            "telegraf": {
                "template_name": "telegraf_install_default.conf.erb",
                "partial_name": "Partial1.conf.erb",
                "app": "App1",
                "env_name": "UAT1",
                "env_type": "UAT",
```

*master/role/Application2_DEV.json*

```
"default_attributes": {
            "telegraf": {
                "template_name": "telegraf_install_default.conf.erb",
                "partial_name": "Partial2.conf.erb",
                "app": "App2",
                "env_name": "DEV1",
                "env_type": "DEV",
```

NOTE : Not all applications need partial template; the partial template is required only when some applications need some customizations or specific requirements, else the default template is rendered

However with time, many applications were onboarded for multiple environments. 
The number of role files were getting out of hand and difficult to track and maintain.

We then planned to create wrapper cookbook for each individual applications, So  that

- We have application/environment specific role files defined in the wrapper cookbook.
- Wrapper cookbook will be pinned to a particular master cookbook version.
- Independently amend wrapper cookbook without making and changes to the master cookbook
  (This is an enterprise mandate, i.e. bump up cookbook version whenever any changes are done to it (other than role files))

So now we have the wrapper cookbooks like this:-

*wrapper1/template/Partial1.erb*

*wrapper1/role/Application1_DEV.json*

*wrapper1/role/Application1_UAT.json*

*wrapper2/template/Partial2.erb*

*wrapper2/role/Application2_DEV.json*

As per the requirements; we want to insulate the base cookbook from all the wrappers;
hence we want to pass the partial template file(which are application specific) from the wrapper cookbook.

We do this by changing the render logic to this;

```
<%= render @partial_name , :cookbook => 'wrapper1' %>
```

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (Cookbook wrapper1 not found. If you're loading wrapper1 from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata) on line #20:

 18:
 19: <% unless @partial_name.empty? -%>
 20:  <%= render @partial_name, :cookbook => 'wrapper1' %>
 21: <% end -%>
 22:
```

When I add dependency of wrapper in the master cookbook; the error goes away and we have a successful converge

However this defeats the purpose of isolating the master cookbook, as for every partial template in wrapper cookbook, I need to add the wrapper dependency in master cookbook metadata.

I hope I was able to explain my requirement. Appreciate if you can suggest if there is any work around or may be some other approach to work this out.

Comment: what is the question? what is the error?

Comment: There is no error per say. The above logic works. My concern that i have to add the wrapper dependency to my master cookbook, and it makes sense ; as the configuration action is happening in the master cookbook, i.e. it requires template info from my wrapper. I am looking for some other work around where i can have custom config in wrapper; and not make any changes to the master when consuming it

Answer (score 0):

create a [custom resource](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources/) in the master cookbook and then utilize it in any recipe that depends on the master cookbook